# Retrive data where date and time are more than tomorrow

Tags: python, django

There's a table in my view named as upcoming. What i want to do is simple, i just want to add some data on that column that is dated greater than tomorrows date. I did this:

```
  upcoming_obj = Events.objects.filter(start_date__year = current.year,
                                         start_date__month = current.month,
                                         start_date__day = current.day>=2)
  where current = datetime.datetime.now()
```

But when i set `start_date__day = current.day+1` it returns tomorrows date which works fine for me as theres another table named tomorrows event. Is there another option or this "`current.day>=2`" makes no sense?

Comment: I think you've got this right.

Comment: but it returns an empty object. i have data that is dated of day after tomorrow in database. but it returns an empty object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import datetime

tomorrow = datetime.datetime.today()+datetime.timedelta(days=1) 

upcoming_obj = Events.objects.filter(start_date__gt = tomorrow)
```

Comment: if you do somenting like this: `upcoming_obj = Events.objects.filter(start_date__gte = tomorrow)` you'll get events with tomorrow date and greater.